# LinkedBlockingQueue first elements are missing

Tags: java, concurrency, cmis

I use the LinkedBlockingQueue for implicit synchronization for my application, but always if I use `queue.take()` or `queue.poll()` the first few elements are somehow missing after getting it from the queue. I have already checked if it's the same object and it is.

Here is my code:

```
for ( QueryResult result : tmpPage ) {
    String objectId = result.getPropertyValueByQueryName( "cmis:objectId" );
    writer.writeFile(objectId ); //Only for debugging reasons to 
                                 //compare the input and the output
    try {
        batchJobs.offer( new Node( objectId ), 1,TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errorLogger.error( e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

The place where I take or poll

```
Node node = null;
while ( !nodes.isEmpty() ) {
    while((node = nodes.take())!=null ) {
        writer.writeFile( node.getObjectID() ); // Only for debugging reasons
        if ( node != null ) {
            //Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Have somebody experienced something similar?

Comment: Can you clarify "the first few elements are somehow missing after getting it from the queue"? Do you mean that after you remove the element from the queue, it is no longer available?   BTW, `if ( node != null )` is unneeded. You guaranteed that `node != null` in the condition on your inner `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Queue take() and poll() method retrieve the data and remove it from the queue.That might be the reason you are loosing the data. If you want to retrieve the data but don't want to delete it, use peek().

Comment: That was my plan to take it out of the queue, but it seems that if I use multiple threads on queue.poll() or queue.take() function, some elements are missing. Do I have to set a lock if I want to take out something from the queue? I thought this class is thread safe.

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact scenario how you are using this?Since take() and pull() are both synchronised methods but both threads might be working on same Object.So the data will should be popped out and printed by both the threads.There are chances that  context switching came to the same thread and same thread calls the poll() again and you would have been looking for thread 2 in next turn.

Comment: Dear Shailesh 

That case which you mentioned was actually the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A queue is a FIFO (first in - first out) data structure. Once you take an object from the queue, it will no longer be a part of that data structure. You would have to put it back on the queue.

If you only want to look at the element, you would want to use a peek().

Answer (score 0):

The problem was which was mentioned by Mr Modi.

> Can you please tell me the exact scenario how you are using this?Since take() and pull() are both synchronised methods but both threads might be working on same Object.So the data will should be popped out and printed by both the threads.There are chances that context switching came to the same thread and same thread calls the poll() again and you would have been looking for thread 2 in next turn